# running delphi application on non delphi pc

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-7

I'm building an application using delphi 7 with ms access 2007 as the database for a client. it runs normally on my laptop (asus) but after I copy the whole project folder and run the Project.exe, it gives me an error "Disk write error".

I've tried googling about "disk write error delphi application" but only found about I/O errors. my application only opens a file after a button click in a form that is called when I click on a submenu, so I'm guessing it's not about I/O..

what is the solution?

thanks in advance

P.S.:

in the project options, the checkbox for building application using runtime packages is already unchecked.

my PC and my client's PC are both using windows 7 32bit (I haven't actually confirmed this with him but I'm guessing he's also using 32bit version because he's not a techy guy)

his PC doesn't have delphi installed

UPDATE :

I forgot that the exact error message was "Disk or network error" instead of "Disk write error".

after googling for the correct error message, I've found out that the problem is that I use a full path for the DataSource in the ADOs' connection string. after I change connection string into "DataSource=.\db\my_db.mdb", the application works perfectly.

even though this question has a negative mark, I'll just leave this solution here in case someone needs it in the future...

Comment: Try to recompilet your program with madexcept (http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) that wil give you some answers. No one here can help you since we can not see your code.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging

Comment: Are the app's datafiles located in one of the folders where Win7 normally prohibits write operations, such as c:\program files etc?

Comment: And You show us the code that causes the error?

Comment: Yes, please include the offending code.  How can we help if we can't see the code that causes the problem?

Comment: I write and maintain several dozen Delphi applications that run daily on as many as 50 machines which do not have Delphi installed, and they all work fine. This is a clear indication that the problem has nothing to do with whether Delphi is installed or not, but has to do with something in your code. As you've provided zero of that code, and not given any information about what your app does, the only possible solution here is for you do some debugging so you can determine what you're doing wrong in your app and fix it. Good luck.

Comment: unfortunately, the error message only appear when I try to run the application on my client's machine (it works perfectly on my pc) which doesn't have delphi installed. the application have quite a few forms so it's going to be really tedious if I have to create an application with different combinations of forms just to check where the problem is..

I thought if one of the guys(or girls) here had a similar experince, you guys can point me to a command that MAY cause the problem so I can debug it faster.

thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Here are some different questions.

The "Disk write error" probably is that you need permissions to write in the folder. A simple test is that you execute your application with "admin permissions" to test this.

Different question is the "using runtime packages" check in project options.

If you compile your application with this check, you need to copy the BPL's needed for your application with the executable.

If you compile with this option unchecked, your exe file include all the libraries for execute (not included DLL's or external dependencies).